# Perl Image::Magick Convert Format

Tags: perl, imagemagick

A few months ago I installed [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aMagick) on my perl server, but now I have unexpected behaviour..

After hours of research, I'm stuck on some problem..

What I'm trying to do is convert an image from .png to .jpg.

There is no problem here.. the problem comes here. basically my converted file ".jpg" is always large than .png after conversion..

here a snippet of my code:

```
my $image = Image::Magick->new;

my  $x = $image->Read($serverPathDir.'/'.$serverFileName);  # an .png file 

    $x = $image->Set( Gravity => 'Center' );
    $x = $image->Resize(geometry=>'435x210'); 
    $x = $image->Set(Quality=>'80%');
    $x = $image->Write($serverPathDir.'/'.'.jpg');
```

After some research and theory, I realized that such problem may exist in specific images.. when I test with other images, the result is more satisfactory but nothing like GIMP (png to jpg)... I don't know what compressor [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aMagick) uses, but seems to be very different like others.. ie: GIMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may have to do with PNG files that are already compressed.

When you convert to another format, you have to decompress the image. Then you compress it in another format, which may not be able to compress it as much as the original format.
Also PNG's with few colors can be compressed even more by using a color palette, containing only the colors actually used.

So it is actually quite likely to find a file where a JPEG version would be larger, if you have a large enough sample size.

You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Comparison_to_JPEG).

I would only convert to JPEG for files which are larger than some arbitrary size, ( Larger files are more likely to be a photograph. ) unless you absolutely need to use the JPEG format. ( For example a program which can't read PNG files )

Answer (score 1):

When converting to jpg and changing the dimension of the original, use a multiple of 8.  So, change your resize to a geometry of '436x216' and see if that helps.

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg) for more

Comment: 436 is not a multiple of 8. I would suggest 448 to keep things in similar ratio to 435x210.

Comment: hi guys,
i followed your sugestions but my problem persists..

Plus, resizing to 448, makes my ".jpg" even more larger

My standart .png have about 159kb.. converted to .jpg ~ 191kb .. 

So weird this behavior.. is there other sugestions?

Thanks All.